# Hiding columns and then showing all jumbles up cell values with array datasource

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I based my logic on the code suggested here http://jsfiddle.net/LkLkd405/4/

I added 2 new items to the default context menu (code from my helpers module)

```
addColHideItemsToContextMenu: function(hot, colsToHide, globalColumns, globalHeaders){

                    var items = hot.contextMenu.defaultOptions.items;
                    //console.log("items: "+JSON.stringify(items));

                    //hide_col based on existing remove_col
                    var hideColItem = {
                              key: 'hide_col',
                              name: 'Hide column',
                              callback: function(key, selection) {
                                 //remove_col code 
                                //var amount = selection.end.col - selection.start.col + 1;
                                //this.alter("remove_col", selection.start.col, amount);

                                //hide_col custom code
                                colsToHide.push(selection.start.col);  
                                var newCols = [];
                                var newHeaders = [];

                                for (var i = 0; i < globalHeaders.length; i++) {
                                    if (colsToHide.indexOf(i) === -1) {
                                        newCols.push(globalColumns[i]);
                                        newHeaders.push(globalHeaders[i]);
                                    }
                                }
                                hot.updateSettings({
                                    columns: newCols,
                                    colHeaders: newHeaders
                                });
                              },
                              disabled: function() {
                                var selected = this.getSelected(),
                                    entireRowSelection = [selected[0], 0, selected[0], this.countCols() - 1],
                                    rowSelected = entireRowSelection.join(',') == selected.join(',');
                                return (selected[1] < 0 || rowSelected);
                              }
                            };

                    items.push(hideColItem);

                    var showAllColItem = {
                              key: 'showall_cols',
                              name: 'Show all columns',
                              callback: function(key, selection) {
                                //var amount = selection.end.col - selection.start.col + 1;
                                //this.alter("remove_col", selection.start.col, amount);

                                  colsToHide = [];
                                  hot.updateSettings({
                                        columns: globalColumns,
                                        colHeaders: globalHeaders
                                    });
                              },
                              disabled: function() {
                                return false;
                              }
                            };

                    items.push(showAllColItem);
                },
```

I then have a server side paging module can receives json objects from the server and converts them to an array of arrays, else new columns cannot be added.

```
EnhancementPager: function(paramObj) {


            var handsontableIntegration = function(rows){// called line 283

                paramObj.handsonDataObjects = rows;//received from the server and not used again
                paramObj.handsonDataArrays =  help.buildArrayFromObjs(rows);
                paramObj.globalHeaders = help.extractColHeaders(rows[0]);
                paramObj.globalColumns = help.buildArrayDataSourceColumnConfig(paramObj.handsonDataArrays[0]);
                paramObj.colsToHide = [];

                if(paramObj.table){
                    var hot = paramObj.table;

                    hot.updateSettings({
                        colHeaders: paramObj.globalHeaders,
                        columns: paramObj.globalColumns
                    });


                    help.addColHideItemsToContextMenu(hot, paramObj.colsToHide, paramObj.globalColumns, paramObj.globalHeaders);
                    hot.loadData(paramObj.handsonDataArrays);

                }
            }
```

This is what the grid looks like on load - notice the values on the top row

[image]

This is what the top row changes to after hiding the column

[image]

Then is I select the show all context item

[image]

The top row changes to this

[image]

I've only been working with handsontable for a few days, it's a really well written and organised js api. But I'm pretty mystified by this behaviour.

Comment: haha yeah this happens sometimes and is usually the fault of the way the data object is modified. can you post a fiddle with this code? you can add a fake data object to act as the server if needed. also as an fyi, I never fully tested that code for hiding/showing cols so this will be a good opportunity to see what other steps need to be taken.

Comment: I posted a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dk0gqhrt/3/ (as close to the organisation of my code as I can make it) it seems to be less faulty with fewer rows but if you play around with it enough, by hiding 2 or 3 columns (also sometimes the wrong column gets hidden), then showing all the jumble does still occur

Comment: doesn't work, it throws several errors, can you fix it?

Comment: I've got it open it does work ... I sent you a collaboration link.

Comment: it works for you because you are local. here are the errors for everyone else who's not on your computer:
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/dk0gqhrt/3/show/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://handsontable.com/dist/handsontable.full.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
fiddle.jshell.net/:1141 
Uncaught ReferenceError: Handsontable is not defined